# strange failure GET in ServerResource with 1024*12+486 length response

Tags: restlet

I wrote a ServerResource below with restlet-android-2.1.4. If the I set SIZE to 1024 * 12 + 485, it works. But if I change SIZE to 1024 * 12 + 486 this handle will pending.

```
public class DataResource extends ServerResource {    
    public static final int SIZE = 1024 * 12 + 485;
    @Get
    public Representation getResource(Representation entity) {
        return new OutputRepresentation(MediaType.ALL) {
            @Override
            public void write(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
                    sb.append('E');
                }
                outputStream.write(sb.toString().getBytes());
                outputStream.close();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Which Restlet HTTP server are you using? Did you add the Jetty or Simple extensions to the classpath?

Comment: I'm using a default restlet Component to start the server. Run this code in a Thread https://gist.github.com/fxp/016f9e39e8f30a3b4edd without jetty or other extensions

Comment: Please try adding org.restlet.ext.simple.jar and dependencies and see if it works better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dive into the code, change the write function in WritableSocketChannel.java(in restlet source code) and it will work.
I don't know whether it's a bug.

from

```
public int write(ByteBuffer src) throws IOException {
    return getWrappedChannel().write(src);
}
```

to

```
public int write(ByteBuffer src) throws IOException {
    int count = 0;
    while (src.hasRemaining()) {
        count += getWrappedChannel().write(src);
    }
    return count;
}
```

According to [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html#write%28java.nio.ByteBuffer%29).

> Some types of channels, depending upon their state, may write only
>   some of the bytes or possibly none at all. A socket channel in
>   non-blocking mode, for example, cannot write any more bytes than are
>   free in the socket's output buffer.